# How do I make a padded background for some views in a ConstraintLayout without nesting layouts?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a group of views in a ConstraintLayout.  I want these views to have a gray background.  I also want the background to have padding around these views.

How do I do this without nesting layouts?

[image: ed]

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/topBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/userImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImage"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#655643"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userImage"
        tools:text="Dream Destinations" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        tools:text="by Someone, 921 discoveries" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> you have to give all constraint proper. And also your root view(Constraintlayout) height not needed to match_parent then change it to wrap_content.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/topBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImage"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#655643"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userImage"
        tools:text="Dream Destinations" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        tools:text="by Someone, 921 discoveries" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: let me know if you want rootView(androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout) height with match_parent. I will update my answer according that

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately I can't just set the bottom constraint to the parent, as I plan to add more views below this header and that will mess it up.  I should have specified that in my question.